# while youtube video selected to play it shows me that Div:is error

Tags: youtube

while youtube video selected to play it shows me that Div:is error
why it shows like this andhow to solve this type of errors

Answer (score 0):

I hope this error of your's doesn't exist while browsing in safe mode. I guess the only solution to the problem is that you have to disable the YouTube MP3 Downloadhelper plugin or any other Downloader Plugin that you have installed. This error is caused by the addon. Or else well update shockwave player.